# Problems with Netbeans re: Rails erb/rhtml intellisense?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, intellisense, erb

I've been using Netbeans for Rails and like it a lot, considering how little I paid for it. But something that bothers me is that when I'm editing an RHTML or ERB file, it doesn't do the code autocomplete - or at least not reliably. Sometimes it shows the appropriate variables and methods that are available on an object after you type the dot operator. Sometimes it ignores the instance variables. **Is there a solution for this?** (Please don't say RadRails).

Oh and one more thing in case anyone has solved this: considering how often I have to type **<%** when I'm in a Rails template, I wish there was some hotkey for autotyping the tag . . . ? I always have to stop and look down at my keyboard to find the **<** and **%** keys before I can type the tag so it's not as trivial as it might sound.

Comment: Nobody answered the first question.  Is there a way to make intellisense better/smarter/faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

http://ruby.netbeans.org/codetemplates-rhtml.html

Type in one of the triggers, then hit the tab key to expand it to the code as given.

Comment: These shortcuts are amazing! I figured there had to be something like that but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to explore using HAML. It's much easier on the hands.